# c# xml schema validation only works on local computer but not on server

Tags: c#, xml, validation, schema

The following XML validation only works on my local computer. When I run the same validation on our test server I get the error message: "simpleType 'schemaversion' has already been declared". Why?

```
XmlSchema schemaSimpleTypes = GetXmlSchemaFromContractAssembly(assemblyContract, "SimpleTypes");
XmlSchema schemaCommonTypes = GetXmlSchemaFromContractAssembly(assemblyContract, "CommonTypes");
XmlSchema schemaMessageType = GetXmlSchemaFromContractAssembly(assemblyContract, messageType);

// Set the validation settings
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
settings.Schemas.Add(schemaSimpleTypes);
settings.Schemas.Add(schemaCommonTypes);
settings.Schemas.Add(schemaMessageType);

// Create the XmlReader object
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(DataConversion.ConvertUtf8StringToStream(xmlDoc.OuterXml), settings);

// Parse the file. 
while (reader.Read())
{
    // go through XML, validating against XSD
    // exceptions are passed to the calling method
};

reader.Close();
```

When I perform the validation without "schemaSimpleTypes" and "schemaCommonTypes", then it does work on the server but not on the local computer and I get following error on the local comupter : "The type 'schemaversion' is not a simple type or has not been declared . "
Here's the code:

```
XmlSchema schemaSimpleTypes = GetXmlSchemaFromContractAssembly(assemblyContract, "SimpleTypes");
XmlSchema schemaCommonTypes = GetXmlSchemaFromContractAssembly(assemblyContract, "CommonTypes");
XmlSchema schemaMessageType = GetXmlSchemaFromContractAssembly(assemblyContract, messageType);

// Set the validation settings
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
//settings.Schemas.Add(schemaSimpleTypes);
//settings.Schemas.Add(schemaCommonTypes);
settings.Schemas.Add(schemaMessageType);

// Create the XmlReader object
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(DataConversion.ConvertUtf8StringToStream(xmlDoc.OuterXml), settings);

// Parse the file. 
while (reader.Read())
{
   // go through XML, validating against XSD
   // exceptions are passed to the calling method
};

reader.Close();
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Right click on 'assemblyContract' and select 'go to definition'.  The assemblycontract is different between machines.

Comment: No, this is the same assembly on both Systems.

Comment: Is the time stamp on the executable the same?

Comment: Yes , I have created a test project including the assemblycontract. so it is on both machines the same.

Comment: With same version of Net and VS?